# using google maps api in an android app

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, google-maps-api-2

I am creating an android app in which I want to take in lat long values and display the address on the map but, I am not able to understand how to get the digital certificate and the key to access the maps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in `eclipse` -> `Preferences->Android->Build` pick SHA1 AB:CD etc then add a semicolon and your app package (AB:CD:EF....DD;com.google.myapp), this is for the debug

for release
`keytool -list -alias youralias -keystore yourkeystore`

pick again sha1

Comment: thank you for the steps. I am working in the linux environment so where do i type keytool -list -alias youralias -keystore yourkeystore

Comment: In the terminal :), it's where you often call `sudo` :)

Comment: perahps I think you can just start with debug key, release signature will be needed only when publishing on play store

Comment: i am not able to edit the SHA1 AB:CD etc to add the package name next to it

Comment: you don't need to edit you need to copy in google developer console web site, you need to create a project and enable google maps android api, then it asks for key signatures, you need to add 1 line with sha1 a semicolon and your package name

Comment: thanks i got it. but i think i went wrong in the procedure to run the demo app. i downloaded the maps util package and dont know where to place it in the sdk folder due to which the libraries are not being imported into my project

Comment: unfortunately the page that explain do to this in eclipse is not very clear: http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html make sure you import `Existing Android Code into Workspace` and not existing project